# Disable location and Activity Recognizing sample still works

Tags: google-play-services, activity-recognition

In the [ActivityRecognition's introduction](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/ActivityRecognition), there is a sentence "To run this sample, location must be enabled." But when I disable "Android Location", ActivityRecognition sample still works. I just want to know is there any different in application behavior when I turn on or turn off location setting. How does it work?

The last question is which sensors ActivityRecognition API uses?

1 more question, is there any way to use "Step Detector Sensor" and "Step Counter Sensor" to detect current user activity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1.I tried the code, and it still work when i disable the `Location`, so I think it not a must, it's better that you open cuz it will give u better idea for what's going on. 2. i think it `step` and `accelerometer` sensor. 3. For `Step detector`  you can also try to use the `Google fit` api.

Comment: Thank you @bjiang. 
1. I found out "Location" is unneccessary. 
2. It's very hard to use "Step Detector", "Step Counter" and "Google Fit" to detect current user's activity, so I decided to work with "Activity Recognition API"